# ValueError: substring not found - Really stuck

Tags: python-2.7

I keep getting this error:

> File "abc.py", line 19, in findBetween  start = s.index(first) +
>   len(first)  ValueError: substring not found

from running this code:

```
   def findBetween(s, first, last):
        start = s.index(first) + len(first)
        end = s.index(last)
        return (s[start:end])
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with the code. Thank you very much for helping!

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure out what you are trying to do but if you want to create a function to return the part of string between two chracters this code will work

```
def findBetween(s, first, last):
  start=s.index(first)+1
  end=s.index(last)
  return s[start:end]
print findBetween("ahellob","a","b")
```

Comment: That's not really what I want to get but I have figured out the problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`index()` throws an exception if the value you are searching is not contained in the string. Same happens if you search for index in an array that doesn't contain the value you are looking for. There is also another (small) flaw in your function : if an `end` match is found before a `start` match, you will return an empty string even if another `end` match is found after the start match.

It might be a slight overkill, but you can benefit from using `re` here. Use this:

```
import re
m = re.search("ab(.*?)cd", "abdddcd")
if m: # Does not fail if string is not found
    print m.group(1) # Prints 'ddd'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I figured it out now.